# Swearing: “bollixed”

Tags: etymology, formality, offensive-language, north-american-english, commonweath-english

> The House Ethics Committee has now hired an outside counsel to investigate its own **bollixed** investigation into the conduct of Representative Maxine Waters.
>  (“The House’s Farcical Self-Investigation”, *The New York Times*, July 24, 2011.)

Is *bollixed* less innocent than it seems?

Is it reasonable to assume that neither writer is aware that *bollix* is a direct adaption of *bollocks* (or *ballocks*), meaning “testicles”?

Finally, can we use it in formal English?

Comment: The *New York Times* actually said ***bollixed***?  Really?  Cool! Guess it’s more acceptable in print than *fucked-up*, at least if the Grey Lady says it. In contrast, the *Economist* **will** write ***fucked up***, but only when citing someone with a literal quote. I should search them for bollixing bits.

Comment: @tchrist *bollixed* has 508 hits on NYT. The Times: "The speaker then said he felt inclined for a bit of fucking."

Comment: Well, you get different numbers of hits for all of *bollixed*, *bollicks*, *bollocks*, and *fuck* at the Times. I still have to  wonder whether national readers all recognize the testicular component; doesn’t take much balls to talk about hidden balls. But even if you don’t, it sure doesn’t sound like “formal English” to me.

Comment: @tchrist - See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harcourt_interpolation

Comment: In the UK, there is potential obscenity, depending on one's definitions of what's obscene. In the USA, _bollixed_ (more common probably as _bollixed up_) has no sexual overtones, or at least no more than _fucked up_ does; i.e, it's rude, vulgar, and offensive language, but nothing sexual is intimated.

Comment: I'd say in the US, "bollixed up" doesn't have any obscenity at all, even in the sense of offensive language. I'd put it on par with British "muddled"...it may be impolite to say that someone muddled something, but the words themselves aren't offensive. There may be some to those familiar with the interjection "bollocks" (which just doesn't exist over here), but it'd be less than for "screwed up" and way less than for "fucked up".

Comment: I can remember my dad using *bollixed up* back in the 1940s meaning “confused”, “fouled up”, et cetera. Never would he have meant something testicular. This was Midwestern USA.

Comment: Important uses of 'bollocks' which have not been mentioned are a) when someone gets 'bollocked' i.e. severely told off, usually by their boss; and b) 'getting your bollocks in a twist', i.e. getting confused over something. The female equivalent is to 'get her knickers in a twist'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact of the matter is regardless of how it's spelled, Americans don't say *bollocks* anywhere near as often as Brits. And even when they do, it's much more likely to be used (and understood) as a low-impact general-purpose profanity, rather than a specific anatomical reference.

I can't find the reference right now, but I'm pretty sure Obama publicly referred to something as being "all bolloxed up" *(in disarray)* recently. I also believe that Americans are much more likely to use the *-xed* spellings than Brits (they did pretty much invent *sox*, after all).

In consequence of the American "sanitisation" and spelling bias, Brits themselves are likely to find written instances of *bollox* less offensive than *bollocks* (this also happens with *asshole/arsehole*).

Related examples of "sanitisation" include [berk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Hunt) *(Berkeley Hunt = cunt)*, Father Ted's [feck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feck) *(=fuck)*, and perhaps Princess Anne's ["Naff off!"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1453_uptodate3/page15.shtml) to obtrusive press photographers.

Comment: You think of ***x*** as American? Modulo the rather icky “sox” (which might be unique to spectator-sports teams), I’d think of it the other way around. I’m thinking of words that in the US are **-ct-** but in the UK lasted longer as **-x-** words. I don’t know whether that still holds; I’ve seen conflicting data. I’m thinking of words like *connection* | *connexion*, *deflection* | *deflexion*, *genuflexion* | *genuflection*, *inflection* | *inflexion*, and so on. The ordering of alternatives is per the current OED online.

Comment: @tchrist: Compare [American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bollox%2Cbollix%2Cbollocks%2Cballocks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) and [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bollox%2Cbollix%2Cbollocks%2Cballocks&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) spellings and frequencies. We Brits talk bollocks five times more than Americans. Or at least, we *write* it five times as often - and when we do, we're less likely to spell it with an "x".

Comment: ...also note that OED is increasingly attempting to "internationalise" itself - it's no longer really appropriate to cite it as a guide to ***British*** usage.

Comment: I doubt whether Americans who haven’t lived in the UK ever say *bollocks* — although Aussies and Kiwis do. I don’t count myself, since as I’ve said, I’m corrupt (by virtue/vice of having lived in the UK, amongst other things). One may call the OED’s current practices attempts at internationalization if one wishes, but I see it as nothing more nor less than trying to embrace English wherever and however it is used by native speakers, not solely in the UK or US. I rather like that, myself.

Comment: @tchrist: So far as I know, most UK media providers don't use OED as their primary reference dictionary for spelling/vocabulary. And many of the ones that *do* seem to be within Murdoch's Sky/Fox/Times/Sun stable - they have an inbuilt bias to do this, being part of a global organisation in the first place.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, Americans who haven't lived in the UK say "bollocks", though, in my experience, only in a way that demonstrates that it is self-consciously being used as a loan word.  And mostly just the sort of American who watches Doctor Who.

Comment: I thought Berk derived from Berkshire Hunt not Berkeley Hunt?

Comment: @DazManCat: OED says *Etymology:  Abbrev. of Berkeley (or Berkshire) Hunt, rhyming slang for cunt.* I assume they put *Berkshire* in second (and in brackets) because it's considered less likely. Their earliest citation *(R. Graves, Lars Porsena, 1929)* actually says *"There are other examples of rhyming slang in connection with words of abuse. E.g.: ‘Gehout you berk.’ Berk = Berkeley = Berkeley Hunt"*. Checking with Google I see little evidence of ***Berkshire** Hunt* except in this context, but the [**Berkeley** Hunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Hunt) had long been famous.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that both words have the same origins, they are not the same, at least in American usage.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollocks) draws a distinction between *bollocks* and *bollix* and states that "To 'bollix things up' is not considered offensive in American English."  [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bollix) defines bollix as "to throw into disorder; also : bungle" without indicating that the term is vulgar or offensive.

It seems the term has a long history of specialized U.S. usage; Merriam Webster dates it to 1937 but there are examples in "respectable" publications as far back as 1902 ([Purdue Debris](http://books.google.com/books?id=D6rOAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA254&dq=bollixed&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5xnFT-WlCpSJ6gHjuejSCg&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=bollixed&f=false), page 254: "I simply wanted to say that I never was any other way except all bollixed up on E.M.F. formula").